# How to use email address to pass in uri/url?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm using jQuery to load some document in to a div. I'm using CodeIgniter. I need to pass an email address of each users in the uri.  How can I do that? @ symbols are not allowed to pass in the uri.

```
$('#studiv').load("<?php echo base_url();?>Student_Data_Controller/loadingdetails/"+email);
```

Comment: URL encode the string. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php .. or JS `email` has the `@`? If so https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `encodeURI()`

```
encodeURI(email)
```

Read [JavaScript encodeURI() Function
❮ JavaScript Global Functions in W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp)

Or can do it in backend([PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)) and able to get desired output as well

Comment: How can I then get back the correct email address in controller ?

Comment: @RandhajaMalshanWanigasekara if there is way to Encode there always another way to decode. use `decodeURI()` **Javascript**

Comment: @RandhajaMalshanWanigasekara happy to help

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

You can replace the `@` with `%40` the same way you would replace a space with `%20`

Comment: How can I then get back the correct email address in controller ?

Comment: this is bad practice .. User won't input `%40` instead `@`